# Attribute 'prefix' has no value

Tags: eclipse, polymer

I am trying to add a prefix to a paper-input element, following [this example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input).

```
<paper-input label="total">
  <div prefix>$</div>
  <paper-icon-button suffix icon="clear"></paper-icon-button>
</paper-input>
```

My main concern is that, when I write that piece of code in my `Example.ui.xml` file, the eclipse editor indicates that there is the following error:

```
"Attribute 'prefix' has no value"
```

Additionally, if I try to execute the code, I receive the following error:

```
Compiling module com.dirigendo.test.Test
Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.dirigendo.test.client.Simulator.SimulatorUiBinder'
Rebinding com.dirigendo.test.client.Simulator.SimulatorUiBinder
Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
[ERROR] Attribute name "prefix" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
[ERROR] Error parsing XML (line 22): Attribute name "prefix" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
[ERROR] Errors in 'com/dirigendo/test/client/Simulator.java'
[ERROR] Line 12: Failed to resolve 'com.dirigendo.test.client.Simulator.SimulatorUiBinder' via deferred binding
[WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
[WARN] com.dirigendo.test.client.Simulator_SimulatorUiBinderImpl
Unification traversed 13255 fields and methods and 1072 types. 1049 are considered part of the current module and 1049 had all of their fields and methods traversed.
[ERROR] Compiler returned false
[WARN] recompile failed
[WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

Could you please explain me how to deactivate this validation? I am aware that there are some roundabouts I could use, but I would really like a solution which would involve not to change the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
<div prefix="prefix">$</div>
```

or

```
<div prefix="true">$</div>
```

Polymer just needs the attribute to be there, for valid XML it needs to have a value. Polymer just ignores the value.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I think that your answer is correct, but I was wondering how to disable the check in Eclipse Mars and GWT compiler, rather than fixing the problem!

Comment: Polymer uses HTML5 where this is valid. In your environment Eclipse seems to assume XML. I don't use Eclipse or GWT. Maybe adding a HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of the file silences Eclipse.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work. I am really interested about knowing how to disable the check in Eclipse Mars and GWT compiler. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to Polymer then.

Comment: I am using Polymer with Eclipse and GWT. The issue is when trying to copy and paste polymer example code in Eclipse.

Comment: But you just want to disable some checking for a text document that contains XML or HTML opened in Eclipse. The question is not related to polymer. It's only about how Eclipse parses attributes without values in such a document.